# Rails 4 issue in includes and fetch associated items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, has-one

I have an issue with the `includes` method in Rails. 
I have this user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :account
end
```

And this account model:

```
 class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :User
    end
```

Now the user model has `:id` and `:names`
and the account model has `:user_id` and `:country`

In another controller i want to fetch and display all the user names with their countries.

I am using this query

```
@users = User.includes(:account).where(some condition)
```

Please tell me what can I add in the query to fetch all the countries associated with the user names? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: `@users = User.includes(:account)` and then `@names  = @users.collect(&:name)`

Comment: i want to show it like this 
@user.each do |f|
f.names
f.account.country
end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user should be plural in the controller as you are getting list of records . like this

```
 @users = User.includes(:account)
```

in view you can do this.

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.names %>
  <%= user.account.country %>
<% end %>
```

As `names` is user attribute, you can fetch directly, while country is `account's` attribute, you can fetch using `user.account.country`

Comment: i am getting undefined method "account"

Comment: can you please share exact error. are you able to fetch account for any user. and all users have account.?

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method `account' for #<Array:0x0000000438e628>):
yes all user have account

Comment: seems like your `user` is an array. have you updated your controller to be plural.

Comment: you can see the updated query actually m also applying some condition of where
actually my project is very big so i have made a short desciption

Comment: i have made one change to the answer in the view file. specifically `<% @user.each do |user| %>` try this now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87463/discussion-between-athar-and-codeprotocol).

Answer (score 1):

If it gives you error like 
NoMethodError (undefined method `account' for #)
then this means you are converting it into an array in controller itself.

Change your code 
eg:

```
@users = User.includes(:account).where('id < 5')
```

And in View

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.name %>
  <%= user.account.country %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what will happen if any record for country field is null... will it still retrieve the further record ?

Comment: if country nil then no prob but if account not associated then it will throw an error

Comment: if account not exists -
user.account.country unless user.account.nil?
OR
user.account.nil? ? 'NA' : user.account.country.nil? ? 'NA' : user.account.country

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we are using includes it by default does an outer join, so there will may be users who does not have any account and you will get error while trying to access user.account.country as user.account is nil and on the nil object it will try to call country method which does not exist.